# Should it be "what" or "where" here?

Tags: questions

I want to ask the bus driver what the closest place to library the bus gets to is.

Do I ask:

> **What's** the closest place to the library do you get to?
>
> Or
>
> **Where's** the closest place to the library do you get to?

Answer (score 2):

> **What's** the closest place to the library *that you go* to?

This asks someone to name the *place* that is closest to the library. (For example, the school)

> **Where's** the closest place to the library *that you go* to?

This asks someone to name the *location* of the place that is closest to the library. (For example, the corner of 5th Ave. and Main St.)

In the context of your example, you could ask either one.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence would be correct if you drop the 'do' in the question. The second sentence may also be used after the same trimming, but the first sentence sounds better to the ears.